# Is there a way to compile FF add-on code

Tags: firefox-addon

I remember downloading FF add-ons to study them when I started developping FF add-ons and some of them where like compiled or encrypted, I don't recall.
Even if it's not really the spirit of all this, I've been asked to look for a solution like that for a FF add-on project : is there a way to compile  FF add-on code so it's not readable when downloaded and unzipped by someone ?
Thank you in advance for you answers.

Answer (score 0):

These add-ons were probably using [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), [JavaScript Compressor](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) or a similar tool. These tools manage to obfuscate the code to some degree but they cannot prevent somebody who is determined from analyzing your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll give feedback if we decide to use this kind of tool.